# simpledialog.askstring() does not regain focus after losing it once and the whole application hangs

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-multithreading

I am basically designing an application, which upon starting pops up a dialog box. it asks for user name. while starting the application from the terminal, a main window opens, then a dialog box pops up. But sometimes it gets focus properly and I am able to input the user name, sometimes it unable to acquire focus. Then the issue begins. The dialog box does not regain focus after clicking on it even, the whole application does not respond. It lefts only one way to close it, is to kill it.

Any idea why this issue is happening randomly? Once application is opened and gets focus properly, I can move the mouse pointer and click where ever I like and regains focus if I click on the dialog box.
The red quit button in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXV09.png) shows dialog box is focused but neither I can enter anything nor close the dialog box.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog
import threading


class GUI(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

    def prompt_username(self):
        username = simpledialog.askstring("User informatiion", "Enter user name:")
        if username:
            print(f"User name: {username}")
        else:
            print("no user name provided")

def connection_thread(*args):
    # some other networking stuffs
    gui = GUI(root)
    gui.prompt_username()

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x400")
threading._start_new_thread(connection_thread, ('',))
root.mainloop()
print("Pogram exited")
```

I was unable to reproduce the issue in previously prepared sample code. Finally I have added another sample, issue can be reproduced using this code.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: We need to be able to copy and paste your code to reproduce this problem. Please follow Bryan's link and provide a short "Complete" code we can test.

Comment: @BryanOakley I will update the code provided tomorrow. Currently I am not having Linux machine and on mac same code works perfectly.

Comment: @Mike-SMT I have prepared a minimal code but unable to reproduce it on Linux. But still I am facing same issue in the original code. steps to reproduce the issue:
1 - git clone https://github.com/AyushSenapati/ChatRoom.git
2 - cd ChatRoom & git checkout work
3 - ./chatServer.py and enter "Y" to run on default config
4 - Now run "./chatClient" , it should be able to connect the server and pops up a dialog box
5 - Now if the mouse pointer is moved before dialog box prompts, the dialog box loses focus. I have tested it on Ubuntu 17.10,
no issues on mac

Comment: Focus is controlled at the GUI so I am thinking the problem lies in your main section of code. You will need to provide a minimal example like Bryan asked for. There are a few reason for providing the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as it often leads to your solving your own problem and if not then we have something to work with.

Comment: @Mike-SMT as I have already mentioned, I am unable to reproduce the problem from my prepared minimal code. That's why I have linked my repository URL[ https://github.com/AyushSenapati/ChatRoom.git ]. Please switch to "WORK" branch to view the latest code, I am having issue with.

Comment: The bigest problem I see in your code is the use of `sleep()`. This will cause problems in your program as it will pause the entire Tkinter instance instead of doing what you think its doing. You need to use the method `after()` instead. Try this and let me know if it helps as I cannot use your linked code due to multiple reasons.

Comment: @Mike-SMT It seems, there is some problem with the particular Linux machine. I ran it in a fresh Ubuntu 17.10 virtualmachine today, It did not find any issues. Everything worked as expected. I have already tried after() but it was restricting to update messages on the text filed, I don't know why.

Comment: Ah. You may need to do a clean install on your Linux machine. Sometimes these things happen. Could be a version bug or something else.

Comment: @BryanOakley I have added a verifiable example.

Comment: Your example can't work. You're calling a function named `test` that you haven't defined.

Comment: The problem is likely related to your use of threads. You should never call tkinter code from any thread except the one which has the root window.

Comment: @BryanOakley Opps!! typo.. Edited the sample code. yeah you are right. I noticed it while trying to debug the code from the beginning.  Calling connection_thread directly from the main thread solves the issue. Thanks